# practical way to run statistical test on the coefficients obtained from ridge or lasso

Tags: hypothesis-testing, lasso, ridge-regression

In the OLS, we can run t-tests on the coefficients obtained from linear regression, but how can we test on the coefficients we obtained in the case of lasso or ridge? What's the common practice in data analysis

Comment: The common practice is not to test them, but if an inference is to be made, you could use a Bayesian approach, or something called “post selection inference”.

Comment: Agreed with @DemetriPananos. For a practical implementation of post-selection inference, see the `selectiveInference` R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectiveInference/index.html  For an overview of the concepts, see Taylor & Tibshirani (2015), "Statistical learning and selective inference": https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1507583112

Comment: Does the post-selection inference only work for Lasso, but not Ridge?

Comment: [Here is a list of similar questions with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=post-selection+infer*++answers%3A1)

Comment: "Post-selection inference" mostly focuses on variable selection methods, like Lasso (or Forward Stepwise and a few others). Lasso will completely drop some of your variables, and post-selection inference ask Qs like: "How do we get CIs or hypothesis tests for the variables that are *still left* in the model?" Meanwhile, Ridge does not drop any variables. It shrinks all the coefficients but does not set any of them to 0. So post-selection inference isn't the right set of tools for Ridge.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750965/confidence-intervals-for-ridge-regression) for why it might not be meaningful to try getting SEs and CIs for Ridge coefficients. On the other hand, if you're OK using a Bayesian approach, you can get the same point estimates as Ridge by doing Bayesian regression with a particular prior. Then you can get credible intervals for the coefficients (and check if these CIs contain 0, if you need an approximation to hypothesis testing).